# "Pointer from integer without cast" warning when opening file.

Tags: c, file, argv

I have this homework to do in C. I'm beginner so it is probably very easy, but anyway I have a problem with it.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv){

    int fd=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    int fileLength=(int)lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
    char buf[fileLength];
    read(fd,buf,fileLength);
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<fileLength; i++){
        printf("%c",buf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I get this error:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘open’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

If I write `"file"` instead of `argv[1]`, everything is ok.

Comment: how are you running the program? you should be doing something like `./program filename` where the filename is the file you want to open.

Comment: `int main(int argc, char  **argv){ ...}`

Comment: Change from `int main(int argc, char* argv)` to `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but using an `int` for a file length, and casting the return type of `lseek`, are wrong. The correct type is `off_t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv){
```

has to be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

See the error?

Answer (score 1):

`char* argv` should be `char* argv[]`

What you did is declaring argv as `char*` and then `argv[1]` becomes a char (which is an integer) instead of `char *`

Answer (score 1):

The correct signature is

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `main()` declaration, which should be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

You defined `argv` as a `char *`, which makes it a single pointer, whereas it's an array of `char *` pointer, with each `char *` element corresponding a command line argument to your program.

The error you're getting is caused by the fact that when you pass `argv[1]` to `open()`, `argv[1]` is a single `char`, while `open()` expects a `char *`.

Another improvement to your program would be checking that `argc > 1` before attempting to use `argv[1]`. This would catch cases when you didn't pass any arguments to your program.

Answer (score 0):

`argv` should be a `char **` not a `char *` also you should run the program like

`./program filename`

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` function's signature is wrong.

It should look like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) // notice how 'argv' is now a 'const char *[]',
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this mate:

```
main () {
    FILE *fin  = fopen ("test.in", "r");
    FILE *fout = fopen ("test.out", "w");
    int a, b;
    fscanf (fin, "%d %d", &a, &b);  /* two input integers */
    fprintf (fout, "%d\n", a+b);
    exit (0);
}
```

instead of "test.in" put your argument, did you try to cast first before?